# java 8 path filter file name

Tags: java, path

I am trying to filter files starting with "EMP" in the folder "C://Temp" and trying to return list of "Paths" i tried below code but always it is returning empty list. Is there any syntax error i am doing?

```
String directoryPath = "C://Temp";                            
String partOfFileName = "EMP";                           
List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(Paths.get(directoryPath))                               
                .filter(line -> line.toString().startsWith(partOfFileName))
                .map(Path::getFileName)                                    
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why do you expect `Path.toString()` to return?

Comment: i am mapping the file name, not the .tostring

Comment: You're filtering on `toString()`.

Comment: my filter is to find out the files strarts with EMP... when i say Files.list it shoul list me out all files in the directory..

Comment: It does, with the full path.

Comment: just an update that  instead of "line -> line.toString().startsWith(partOfFileName)" if i mention "line -> line.toString().contains(partOfFileName)" it is fetching me the file name, however i am interested in absolute path of  the file.. is there any way i can map absolute path?

Comment: Use `toAbsolutePath`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are checking the full path, you may want to check the immediate directly by using "endsWith" instead of "startsWith".

Right now if you are in "folder1/folder2/test" and you use startsWith, it is going to check and try to filter on the first directory, "folder1".

```
   try {
        List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(Paths.get(directoryPath))
                .filter(line -> line.endsWith(partOfFileName))
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Path.toString()` returns the full path representation. If you want to filter by the file name, call `getFileName()` within your filter operation:

```
String directoryPath = "C://Temp";
String partOfFileName = "EMP";
List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(Paths.get(directoryPath))
        .filter(path -> path.getFileName().startsWith(partOfFileName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: by getFileName also it is still not retrieving any results

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, this solved it

```
Files.list("path/to/the/directory").
        filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("the name I want")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```